# How do I make "file:///home/lochana/www.google.com" as "www.google.com" in the address bar?

Tags: html

I created simple html script for testing hyperlink.
This html file is located in (I saved)"/home/lochana" and when I open it with the browser, it shows "file:///home/lochana/hrf.html" in the address bar, which is fine and makes sense to me.

In the script, I made a hyperlink in this way

```
<a href="www.google.com">Google Home</a>
```

Now the question is as I click on the "Google Home", it goes to "file:///home/lochana/www.google.com" instead "www.google.com".

I'm a beginner to html and I need some help with this. thank you

Comment: just update http://www.google.co.in

Comment: use `http://<address>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you should achieve this by including `http:` infront of the www

**HTML**

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">Google Home</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to change to a different hostname, then you can't start a URL with a hostname. You have to start with either the scheme, or the double slash (to be relative to the current scheme). Since you are changing scheme too (from `file` to `http`) then you can't use the scheme relative approach.

```
http://www.google.com
```

Answer (score 1):

you forget to add HTTP:// in your code

so replace

```
<a href="www.google.com">Google Home</a>
```

with

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">Google Home</a>
```